# Anyone able to run Ubuntu 20.10 or 20.04.1 LTS on new Dell XPS 13 9310 Touch laptop?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, dell, xps, 20.10

I naively bought a new **Dell XPS 13 9310 Touch** laptop thinking I would be able to run Ubuntu on it.

When I bought it the only choice for pre-installed OS was Windows so it came with Windows 10 Home.

It's a USA model with:

Intel Core i7-1185G7 11th gen EVO, Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650 (2x2) and Bluetooth 5.1, Intel Iris Xe graphics, 16GB RAM, and 1TB SSD

When I boot from the USB drive to install, I get to the boot menu that lets me choose Ubuntu, safe graphics, UEFI settings, etc.

After selecting Ubuntu (or safe graphics) I get errors like:

```
74.070544] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

and the system hangs.

Does anyone have any advice?

Is it possible to run Ubuntu on this system?
Thanks.
Shawn

Answer (score 2):

Your new machine [*is* certified to run](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202007-28046), but the kernel used for the certification is higher than the one that ships with Ubuntu 20.04. What I would suggest is that you grab the Dell-made installation .iso [from Dell themselves](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/drivers/osiso/ubt20). Enter your service tag, and you’ll get the proper image that includes all the drivers you’ll need for the network, Bluetooth, touch screen, and everything else.

The installation process with the Dell image should be pretty much the same as the stock installation process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. I did have to change en-ie in the link to en-us. When I entered my service tag it says there is a recovery image but it only shows Windows 10 Home download.

Comment: Turns out that I had 2 bad flash drives! I was finally able to install from standard Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What horrible luck to have *two* faulty devices. Glad you could solve the problem, though 